# Noise during RS-485 operation

Tags: noise, rs485, step-down

I have a switching step-down power supply SCM1301A, from which the entire circuit is powered, namely the microcontroller, op-amp, RS-485. I digitize the signal coming from the microwave module, having previously amplified and filtered it. The signal band I need is 5-1000Hz. Everything works fine until I start the exchange via the RS-485 interface. When exchanging via the RS-485 interface, strong noise appears in the signal.
[image]
I tried everything I could to combat this, but I still couldn’t find a solution...
Next I will describe everything that I tried and how it affected:

1. Noise if RS-485 does not work somewhere at the level of 10-15 units.
2. If the power is 12 V and I start the exchange via RS-485 at a speed of 38400 Baud / s, then the noise will be 195-200 units. If the speed is 2400 baud/s, then the noise is 205 units. If the speed is 230400 Baud/s, then the noise is 45 units. Moreover, in the program I have a number of digital filters, where I divide the entire 5-1000Hz band into 5 200Hz bands. And I see how, as the exchange rate increases, the main noise peak also moves to a higher frequency.
3. Next, I tried changing the supply voltage at the input of the switching stabilizer. The RS-485 exchange rate is always 38400 Baud/s. Power supply 10 V, noise 50 units. Power supply 12 V, noise 200 units. Power supply 24 V, noise 70 units. Power supply 30 V, noise 85 units.
4. Moreover, if you look at what happens at the inductor of the switching stabilizer with a 12 V supply, there is no exchange via RS-485: Fig.1. The same thing only there is an exchange via RS-485: Fig. 2. It’s hard to see here, but there is a slight twitching of the signal in the area of ​​the maximum amplitude swing.
   [image]
   [image]
5. Stabilizer output in the absence of exchange via RS-485: Fig.2. The same thing only with exchange via RS-485: Fig. 3. Here I did not notice any changes...
   [image]
   [image]
6. I tried to connect 470uF Low ESR capacitors in parallel with capacitor C2, but this had no effect.
7. If the RS-485 microcircuit is written from a separate source, the noise during the exchange completely disappears.
8. Next, I raised my 3.3V supply to 3.9V and powered the RS-485 chip through the LDLN025M33R linear regulator. 3.9V is supplied to the input of the LDLN025M33R, and I saw 3.3V at the output. And yet there was still noise when exchanging via RS-485. Next, I powered the LDLN025M33R chip from a separate external 4.5V source. And when exchanging via RS-485, the noise completely disappeared.
9. If you install an RC filter R = 100 Ohm, C = 1000 μF in front of the power input of the RS-485 microcircuit, then the noise becomes much less, but does not disappear completely.

Perhaps I forgot something, if you have any additional questions, write.

Additional Information:
I ran a series of tests and compiled a table. Columns on the right show noise on ADC with RS485 BPS when running (0 for not running)

LDLN025M33R, SSP7903: LDO ; SCM1301A: Buck

| What is done | 0 | 1200 | 4800 | 19200 | 57600 | 230400 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MCU/ANALOG: input 9-36V -> SCM1301A 5V -> LDLN025M33R 3.3V. RS-485: external 3.3V | 2-3 | 3-4 | 5-6 | 4-5 | 3-4 | 2-3 |
| MCU/ANALOG: input 9-36V -> SCM1301A 5V -> LDLN025M33R 3.3V. RS-485: input 9-36V –> SSP7903-3.3 | 3-5 | 18-20 | 30-32 | 17-18 | 9-10 | 4-5 |
| MCU/ANALOG/**RS-485**: input 9-36V -> SCM1301A 5V -> LDLN025M33R 3.3V | 4-5 | 62-63 | 109-110 | 78-79 | 46-47 | 12-13 |
| MCU/ANALOG/**RS-485**: input 9-36V -> SCM1301A 3.3V | 12-15 | 117-120 | 265-268 | 198-202 | 120-124 | 30-33 |
| MCU/ANALOG/**RS-485**: input 9-36V -> SCM1301A 3.3V + 470µF solid capacitor in parallel with C2 | 13-15 | 124-127 | 280-285 | 210-215 | 130-133 | 37-39 |
| MCU/ANALOG: input 9-36V -> SCM1301A 3.3V. RS-485: through a 10 Ohm resistor. 470µF solid capacitor in parallel with C2. LPF 34Hz. | 12-15 | 90-95 | 180-195 | 69-71 | 29-31 | 12-15 |

The voltage did not change in all tests and is equal to 12V.

I attached part of the PCB layout. The board is double-sided. The second side is completely filled with grounding.
[image]

Comment: Lines A and B connect to the RS-485 to USB converter.

Comment: Can you explain how things are powered? To where you communicate with RS-485? Do devices on RS-485 bus share a common ground reference? Or are some devices powered with floating mains supplies? Or batteries?

Comment: No ground wired on the SCM1301A ?

Comment: @Justme I have UART to RS-485 on my board. Then, through pins A and B, it is connected to an RS-485 to USB converter to a PC. There is a program on the PC that communicates with the microcontroller via reception and transmission. Devices on the RS-485 line have a common ground, but whether it is there or not, the noise is the same. I tried to write my board from the battery, but the noise is still there.

Comment: @Antonio51 I just made a mistake in the diagram. In fact, there is common land there. I'll fix the diagram now.

Comment: Probably layout related on top of the previous comments on decoupling. What does your PCB look like? How many layers? What goes on which layer? What does your probe setup look like?

Comment: @winny I added a printed circuit board to make it clearer

Comment: @winny I wrote: The board is double-sided, the second side is completely a grounding area.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. What does your probe setup look like for the oscillograms under point 5?

Comment: @winny the probe was setup on + C8 capacitor. At the output of the switching power supply.

Comment: With long ground lead/clip or very short pigtail like this: https://www.eevblog.com/2014/03/21/eevblog-594-how-to-measure-power-supply-ripple-noise/

Answer (score 3):

A bit of ripple on your digital supply is normal when current drawn varies (for example when operating a RS485 transmitter, blinking a LED, etc). The switching converter then convert varying current draw into varying noise spectrum. The real issue is not preventing this, because that's not really possible, switching converter is going to do it anyway. Besides, MCU and RS485 don't need very clean power supply.

The issue is preventing this noise from getting into your analog circuit.

[image]

Power supply voltage is used as an input to your analog circuit.

The top right 3V3 is filtered by a 10µF cap, presumably a MLCC, with 50k impedance, which forms a lowpass filter with a cutoff of 0.3Hz. That should be good, although if C15 is a ceramic it will act as a piezo microphone, with the high impedance of R26 and 266 you may have some noise in the output from board vibratin.

Top left 3V3 is filtered by 150R+100µF, so the lowpass corner frequency is 10 Hz, but if this is a general purpose aluminium cap it will have ESR in the tens of ohms so supply noise will not be attenuated much. This is the most likely culprit.

On the bottom left 3V3 is output directly to power the sensor which may be sensitive to it.

There is also the question of the opamp's PSRR, which is probably not going to be that good at the noise frequency generated by the DC-DC.

The other hidden input is the MCU's ADC voltage reference. But the opamp on the right has quite a lot of gain which amplifies any noise picked up, so I think reference noise effects will be small compared to noise injected into the signal.

I'd say replace C11 with a low ESR model to diagnose. Then try powering the sensor with a clean 3V3 from a bench supply.

Can't see the layout, so no comment, but if the DC-DC is close to the analog circuit it can also pump noise into it via magnetic, capacitive, or common impedance coupling via ground.

---

[image]

Red is AC gain from input to output.

Green is AC gain from 3V3 powering the transistor to output.

Blue is AC gain from 3V3 powering the opamp's midsupply reference to output.

Due to the circuit's high gain, and the lack of PSRR in the input stage (the transistor gain stage has almost none), supply noise will appear amplified at the output, by a rather large factor, almost 25dB. So RS485 is not the problem, but it reveals the problem, which is sensitivity to power supply noise in the analog stage.

Noise due to the sensor's PSRR will also be amplifier by the circuit's gain, but I have no idea what the sensor is, so can't comment.

Suggestions:

- Replace the transistor with an opamp having high PSRR in the frequency range of interest, or move the transistor's gain into the first opamp filter stage to eliminate the transistor.
- Set the buck to something like 4-5V and use separate 3V3 LDOs for: 1) analog circuit, sensor, and MCU with RC filter ; 2) everything else.
- Add electrolytic capacitor in parallel with C4

Comment: I would add some inductance to the filter of the analog circuit as well.

Comment: @bobflux C11 is a tantalum capacitor. Now I’ve added another 470 µF Low ESR capacitor in parallel to it. When exchanging via RS-485, the noise remained. I tried to power the microwave module from a separate linear power supply, the noise decreased, but did not disappear completely. Also, now I installed, set the output voltage to 4V on the pulse source, and then fed it to the linear source LDLN025M33R, and from the output of LDLN025M33R I powered the entire circuit, except for the RS-485 converter. The noise also decreased, but did not disappear completely.

Comment: It decreased, but by how much? For this kind of debugging it helps to keep track of everything. You can add it to your question. I suggest to use a table with two columns: test condition and result. Also please post layout. You can also try to disable the switching converter and power the whole device with 3V3 from a LDO or a clean linear supply. Also please post layout.

Comment: @bobflux I tried to add a table with all the tests, but for some reason it does not display normally... I also added a printed circuit board.

Comment: I tried to fix the table, looks OK. There's a LED on the board, but it's not in the schematic. I don't see a resistor in series which is weird. Is the LED used when noise occurs? Why I'm asking this: we're looking for something that draws varying supply current, so a blinking LED would definitely do that. There's also what looks like a wireless transmitter, is it active?

Comment: @bobflux “LED” are contacts for the jumper, this is the input of the microcontroller. “Contacts for a wireless transmitter” - nothing is installed there now either. “something that draws varying supply current” is exactly RS-485. When sending a package, it pulses current, I assume. Because if the interface is not active, there is no noise, as can be seen from the table. If the microcontroller contacts RX, TX, which now go to RS-485, are connected to an external UART to USB converter, then there is no noise.

Comment: I edited the answer. I guess you used the transistor circuit because you need lower noise than what the opamp can do, the irony being that the low noise circuit is the cause of the noise due to low PSRR... I'll try to work something out, but I will need data about the sensor (datasheet, or at least its output impedance) and also what transistor and opamp you're using.

Comment: @bobflux The signal entering the transistor and going further comes from the BGT24LTR11N16 chip (output I), I use a BC847C transistor due to the small Noise figure to pre-amplify the signal. I use MCP6L02 as an op amp. Its noise is much greater than that of a transistor and is equal to 24 nV/Hz at a frequency of 10 kHz. If you look at the datasheet for this transistor, then in the 10Hz region its noise will be about 150 nV/Hz, taking into account my gain, if I do not use a preamplifier on the transistor, I will get a very strong final noise.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I think you need to redesign the analog part for higher supply rejection and use separate LDOs. Perhaps an opamp with a bit more gain-bandwidth product too, so it has higher PSRR too.

Comment: @bobflux I tried test No. 2. I powered the MCU and analog part: 9-36V -> SCM1301A 5V -> LDLN025M33R 3.3V. And I powered RS-485 with input 9-36V –> SSP7903-3.3. But I still got noise, although not as big, it was still there. I'll try an op amp with a higher bandwidth.

Comment: In this experiment what powered the sensor?

Comment: The same as the analog part and MCU

Comment: OK, please add it to the table in the question to keep track of it. Now assuming the output of LDLN025 was clean enough at low frequency, I'd check if the problem comes from HF noise from the switcher. You can clean it up with a lowpass filter at the input side of the LDO, say 100 ohms and 10µF. The 10µF has to be surface mount  ceramic cap soldered directly to the ground plane for low inductance (you can scratch the soldermask off).

Comment: @bobflux Can I keep the transistor, but somehow reduce the noise in its power supply?

Comment: Well I guess you want input referred noise in the µV range and you're not going to get that with unfiltered power supply from switcher. You have to study the various options: transistor, low noise opamp, or the usual low noise amplifier built with a transistor as low noise input stage inside the feedback loop of an opamp. Get an idea of the PSRR of each option, and balance the budget between PSRR in the amplifier, and how much work the LDOs will need to do.

Comment: But there's also the sensor and you need a clean VCC/2 voltage reference, so you will need a clean supply. There's no mention of PSRR in the sensor datasheet, which is really a problem. What I think is happening is your circuit measures "something" which is a combination of actual signal and error due to supply ripple. If the current draw changes due to RS485 then the supply ripple will change, so the amount of error changes. But even when the measurement looks like it has no noise, it may still have constant error due to ripple, but you don't notice it because it's constant... hmmm

Comment: Also you need HF filtering (ferrite bead + cap) to remove HF noise because the analog circuit will be sensitive to it. HF can be rectified by nonlinear elements (transistor junctions) which brings it down into your signal bandwidth, creating error. When RS485 draws current, switcher behavior changes, so HF noise changes, so this error changes also. Thus you need good supply filtering both at LF (with LDOs) and HF (ferrites and caps).

Comment: The problem with the transistor alone is it has almost zero PSRR. So if you want X amount of noise on the collector... you need less noise on the power supply, and your frequency is low, which means you need a voltage reference with very low 1/f noise for your power supply, and you can't really use caps to filter it well, because your frequency is low ;)

Comment: @bobflux you are talking about "the usual low noise amplifier built with a transistor as low noise input stage inside the feedback loop of an opamp".  can you tell me more about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152069/discussion-between-bobflux-and-red15530).